# Is webpack including whole React library or only what is imported

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I was looking into three libraries to start the private project that will help me know more JavaScript. Those libraries are React, Preact and Svelte. Knowing that every library that I listed is guided by different (or similar) principles React is the most popular one. But two others are faster / smaller and these are the two attributes that I would like to follow.

**My question is:**
When React is imported...

```
import React from 'react';
```

... is there a way to make it smaller using webpack to bundle only what I will use from the main library?

Maybe there is something I don't understand or misunderstand when I was reading the documentation for React and webpack?

Comment: I’ve been playing with svelte and I really like the approach they have taken ie. no virtual dom tree, just normal javascript and html-dom tree. The innovation of svelte is that you can have all resct type goodies while programming and then in compilation those goodies are transformed to js, html and css. I find this very brilliant and I believe this is the way to future.

Comment: I'm also interested in Svelte but there are not a lot of jobs with it. That is why I asked about making React build smaller to the edge.

Comment: I don't believe React itself is tree-shakable, sadly. Also bear in mind that "react" is quite small, most of the code comes from "react-dom".